# Importing multiple vue.js components using promise.all()

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, webpack, vuejs2, promise

I'm trying to import multiple Vue.js 2.7 components simultaneously, and this is my progress so far. However, I'm unsure if I'm correctly managing the asynchronous imports or just running everything in sequence.

```
importComponents(modules) {
    return Promise.all(modules.map(this.importModule, this));
},

async importModule(module) {
    try {
        const fileName = module.idx.charAt(0).toUpperCase + module.idx.slice(1);
        const path = `./modules/${fileName}.vue`;

        this.$options.components[module.idx] = async () => {
            return await import(/* webpackChunkName: "my-modules" */ `${path}`);
        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Failed to import the component ${fileName}: ${error.message}`);
    }
}
```